# How can I create an associative array using for each?

Tags: php, arrays

I am selecting checkboxes and want to save in an associative array with current page number `$_GET['page_no']` as it's index, but only 1 value goes in, why no other?

```
$pageno = $_GET['page_no']; //Say page no is 1
$_SESSION['selected_vals'] = array();
foreach($_POST['record_num'] as $throw_rec_nums) {
    $_SESSION['selected_vals'][$pageno] = $throw_rec_nums;
}
```

What I expect

```
$_SESSOION['selected_val'] (
   [1] => 24
   [1] => 46
   [1] => 56
)
```

But I only get 24 even if 3 checkboxes are selected

> Note: $_GET['page_no'] is returned as array

Comment: Can you clarify the "but only 1 value goes in" part?

Comment: Please, post you checkboxes html.

Comment: @FabianoLothor If am using `$_GET['record_num']` it is obvious that am using `<input type="checkbox" name="record_num[]" />`

Comment: What you expect is impossible.  You can't have multiples values for a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pageno` is not incrementing. In order for more than one value to be added to the array, it needs to be incremented while in the loop.

A solution would be something like:

```
$_SESSION['selected_vals'][$pageno][] = $throw_rec_nums;
```

That way all record numbers would be saved to the array at the page number specified.

Comment: ok but that creates array inside an array and uses incremened index, any idea I can keep 1 for all ? and thank you +1

Comment: @CreepyFrog: Arrays can only have *one* value per key.  What you want is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Only 1 value goes in because your are replacing $_SESSION['selected_vals'][$pageno] value on each loop of foreach.

try create a counter to index it

it is a option

```
$_SESSION['selected_vals'] = array();
$_SESSION['selected_vals'][$pageno] = array();
foreach($_POST['record_num'] as $throw_rec_nums) {
    $_SESSION['selected_vals'][$pageno][] = $throw_rec_nums;
}
```

Comment: Is impossible to index all with 1 ... (think with me) how can you access some value if all is index in same key? like you expect, with value may return $_SESSION['selected_val'][1]?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an array as array index. You will have to iterate over $pageno too, for example with next():

```
$array[current($pageno)] = ...;
next($pageno);
```

Note that this will only work if you make sure rt that $pageno actually IS an array and contains enough elements.

Comment: I am using foreach so the value returned is not an array :)

Comment: But you don't foreach over $pageno and said that was an array. Well, now I see your expectation, this is just impossible. Keys are unique.